# TestFlight review same as AppStore review?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

Does anyone know if the TestFlight review process is the same as the AppStore review process?

We need to test if our app is eligible (if Apple approves it) for the AppStore but can't wait 10 days to get the result. So our idea is to submit the app to external testers via TestFlight, which usually takes 2-3 days...

Thanks

Comment: It isn't the same, AppStore review is stricter

Comment: I've found TestFlight reviews to be quicker. But the average App Store review time is currently sitting around 5 days, not 10. http://appreviewtimes.com/